# How can I detect whether I'm running on a graphical system within early-init.el?

Tags: gui-emacs

I use GNU Emacs (28.2 (build 2, x86_64-w64-mingw32) of 2022-09-13) on Windows mostly, so I have set some modes in my `early-init.el` to prevent annoying flickering:

```lisp
(tool-bar-mode -1)    ; Setting these in init.el is too late on Windows.
(scroll-bar-mode -1)  ; They will flicker. It's worse for other frame options.
```

However, these lead to issues whenever I use Emacs from the terminal, for example within WSL (GNU Emacs 27.1) with the same configuration:

```sh
$ emacs -nw --eval \
    '(progn (with-current-buffer "*Warnings*" (append-to-file nil nil "/dev/stderr")) (kill-emacs))' \
    2> warnings \
  && cat warnings
```

```
Warning (initialization): An error occurred while loading ‘/home/zeta/.emacs.d/early-init.el’:

Symbol's function definition is void: tool-bar-mode

To ensure normal operation, you should investigate and remove the
cause of the error in your initialization file.  Start Emacs with
the ‘--debug-init’ option to view a complete error backtrace.
```

Usually, I would wrap both mode setup calls within a check for `(display-graphic-p)`, i.e.

```lisp
(when (display-graphic-p)
  (tool-bar-mode -1)
  (scroll-bar-mode -1))
```

This is how most questions are answered here on Emacs SE: use that and you're golden.

However, **there is no display during `early-init.el`**:

> `‘~/.emacs.d/early-init.el’`.  This file is loaded **before the** package
> system and **GUI is initialized** [taken from (info "(emacs) Early Init File"), emphasis mine]

This method does not work and the scroll bar and tool bar are shown. How can I reliably detect whether I'm running Emacs on a terminal **within `early-init.el`**? The documentation mentions window-setup-hook, but that runs too late and the GUI flickers on Windows, as the scroll bars are shown for a split second.

Comment: Off-topic: “*I use GNU Emacs (28.2 (build 2, x86_64-w64-mingw32) of 2022-09-13) on Windows mostly*” -- v29.1 for MS-Windows has been released; it's worth a try.

Comment: @shynur I'm aware, and that's how I noticed that some parts of `early-init.el` do not work as intended :). Some parts of my Emacs configuration are not currently Emacs 29 ready though, mainly the package bootstrapping only during the initial `use-package` install (which is now no longer required)

Comment: @Zeta Note, that disabling elements of the GUI in `early-init.el` (only) might not give an affect creating a new frame, f.i.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check the value of `initial-window-system`.

For example, if you are using Emacs on MS-Windows, then the value should be `nil` when under TUI, `w32` when under GUI.

---

> ##### 41.1.1 Summary: Sequence of Actions at Startup
>
> 8. If not running in batch mode, it initializes the window system that the variable `initial-window-system` specifies...
>    If the value of `initial-window-system` is *windowsystem*, then the appropriate implementation of the initialization function is defined in the file `term/`*windowsystem*`-win.el`.

Though it must be noted that [`(info "(emacs) Early Init File")`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Early-Init-File.html) recommends against moving customizations to the `early-init.el` file, because

> customizations related to GUI features will not work reliably in early-init.el

Comment: AFAICT, this is the only way to check in `early-init.el`, but do not use this method anywhere else. See [Window Systems](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Window-Systems.html).

Comment: This [mailing list thread](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/emacs-devel/2010-10/msg00716.html) adds context to why `initial-window-system` docstring says "Use of this variable as a boolean is deprecated."

Comment: I shall say this kind of thing shouldn't be done in `early-init.el`. But since OP asked this question, then I will answer this question. As for what OP is trying to implement by solving this problem -- "*prevent annoying flickering*", that can be another question.